# Android DownloadService BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() called twice, why?

Tags: android, service, download

I'am using DownloadReceiver for downloading mp4 files in my application, but I encountered an issue when the broadcast receiver onreceive() method is called twice for the same downloadId. I google it and I found that also others are writting about this issue. I'm using Android ICS.

Somebody knows about this Issue ?
Is there a workaround ?

Yes, most of you probably will say "Write your own download manager", I don't have time for that, but if you could propose a third party (free) download manager it would be heplful.

Thanks,
Barna

Comment: I can only paste the receiver part :
   <receiver android:name=".receivers.DownloadReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Currently my workarround is to keep all downloadId-is in a list, and if terminated I remove from there, and in this way the second onreceiver callback for the same downloadId will be thrown away. This is a hack, I need to find what is the problem...

Comment: There are no ideeas ?